# MISRA C++ 2008 Rule 5-2-3 Advisory: Casts from a base class to a derived class should not be performed on polymorphic types

Tags: c++, casting, polymorphism, misra

In the following example:

```
class A
{
public:
    A();
    virtual ~A();
    int getID() const;

private:
    int m_ID;
};

Class B : public A
{
public:
    B();
    virtual ~B();
    int getBid() const;

private:
    int m_Bid;
};

bool test(const A* const p_A)
{
    if(5U == static_cast<const B* const>(p_A)->getBid())
    {
         ....
    }
    else
    {
         ...
    }
}
```

I have MISRA 5-2-3 reported, but i don't now how to resolve it.

MISRA 5-2-3: Casts from a base class to a derived class should not be performed on polymorphic types.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The MISRA checker is right. You should not do a `static_cast`.

You need to understand Polymorphism better. When calling your function

```
bool test(const A* const p_A)
```

also a pointer to the derived class can be used. And, by using the vtable, the correct function will be used. So, do not downcast.

But, you must update your base class. Please add a pure virtual function

```
virtual int getBid() const = 0;
```

In the base class. Then you can override the this function in your derived class.

```
int getBid() const override;
```

If then a other function calls your `bool test(const A* const p_A)` with a pointer to the derived class, then the correct function will be called.

Comment: If i need to add all methods in my base class, my derived class is useless. For example, if i create a new class C who derived of class A, i will have methods for B in C, no ? Because methods for C will be in A.

Comment: In this case you need to start your function with the derived class pointer B*, because A* does not have this function.

Comment: Okay, i see, i go to make my function with B, thanks for your help.

Comment: The base class member function should be virtual, but the base class doesn't necessarily have to be turned into an abstract base class - that depends on the OO design. It's not obvious to me what these classes should do.